# How do you get an activity to resolve higher up in a Share via menu?

Tags: android, sharing, intentfilter

I have an activity that has the following intent filter:

```
<intent-filter android:label="Name Of Activity">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

However, if I try to share some plain text, for example, from the browser's "Share link" option, the activity appears at the very bottom of the list with several other actions/apps that are far less relevant to sharing this type of content.

How can I improve the intent filter so that the OS recognizes that this can handle this type of content better, so it doesn't have to be below things that are far less relevant to the user?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik it's not possible, the options seem to always be displayed in alphabetical order.

Comment: Wow, I feel stupid.   I guess I didn't even notice that.  I figured it was similar to queryIntentActivities() which orders it by best to worst match.  Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Some manufacturers customize the list to put preferred providers higher on the list in some apps.